# Best way to unwrap angle without stretching?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I guess I'm doing something worng, which others ways it may be unwrapped? 
[image]

if I dont add this seams it would be very streaked, if I do than my UV overlaps.

Comment: You just need another seam along the edge where that quad is attached (it becomes its own island), or along the "long" quads' attached edges. The bottom line: more seams = less distortion (good), more islands (bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Solved by adding this triangle part to other part of UV. If you have any recommendations would be happy to see them.

Comment: Would have done it in exactly the same way. Good use of the UV space and no stretching. Depending on the model and its purpose, that's more important than having fewer cuts.